# Import 50+ images and create a 3d model

Tags: modeling

Is this possible with Blender?

Have clay characters that I can shoot on greenscreen. Trying to find a way to take as many photos as needed, import them into Blender or something before Blender and give it 10-20 basic movements.

At the moment I am doing stop motion, but since clay chars can not move hands, legs, head - I would like to make them more natural.

Have not used Blender yet, but will spend good amount of time learning it, if I am on the right track with my idea.

Comment: You are basically talking about photogrammetry. There are several free programs available to convert images to 3d models which can be imported into blender.

Comment: Thx @Ratt . Would MeshLab be a good choice ?

Comment: Personally, (This is just an opinion) I would think carefully before going down the route of photogrammetry, for animation. Your clay models, to be clay models, must have quite simple forms: modeling from reference pictures - even if you have to learn it, _might_ wind up being quicker, and yield better topology for deformation.. it depends. .. I could easily be wrong in your particular case. ( I was once a stop-motion animator )

Comment: To replace the clay with plasticine sounds to be the best idea. :-) If you really have a lot of time to get into 3D, it will worth it. At first you can even outsource the models creation, and concentrate on the animation itself, lighting, effects, and all the familiar movie-making stuff. Then eventually you will find, that it's easier to create a model from nothing with just a mouse clicks, than from a piece of real clay.

Comment: @RobinBetts. Clay models are quite complex (polymer clay to be precise), takes around 15h to make one, and are big source of my income. So, I can not do the model in 3d before I make it from polymer as there is possibility I will not be able to make it from clay :). Trying to do one step at the time so would like to import one model and go on from there, learning movie-making stuff later on. From your experience would you recommend MeshLab for my first step or all of the software are more or less the same for photogrammetry ? Thx.